# Merge columns from Multiple Sheets into Summary Sheet without blanks

Tags: vba, excel

I have many sheets of which some are **A, B, C and D.**
Each of them have different data sets, however columns **E,F,G** have the same type of data.

I would like to merge the data from the columns E,F,G of the sheets A, B, C and D Paste in **Columns A,B,C** of **Sheet Summary**.

The problem I am facing is that the range E2:G(last row with data) has empty rows in the beginning and also in the Middle. Example: E2:G10 is blank and data might be present from E11:G30. This is making my copy paste erroneous.

The Following is the Code I have written. But, for some reason the data in the Sheet D is altered. Also, as I did not know how to exempt empty rows while copying, I used a separate code block to delete the empty rows at the end of copy paste activity in the Sheet Summary.

```
Sub CopyRange()
Dim bottomD As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"))
ws.Activate
bottomD = Range("E" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E2:G" & bottomD).Copy Sheets("Summary").Cells(rows.Count,"E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Next ws

Dim r As Range
Dim rows2 As Long
Dim i As Long
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
rows2 = r.rows.Count
For i = rows2 To 1 Step (-1)
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: To start with, why do you have empty rows - this is not advisable (as you no doubt have learned)? Sorting your data first is an easy way to eliminate your blank rows.

Comment: I wrote code to display the data only when a condition is met. So the end list has blanks in between the range.

Comment: If you need to maintain the original row numbers in the summary sheet you might use `Ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count` instead of `.End(xlUp).Row`. But you would need to define your range using VBA notations (as opposed to "Excel notations" like "E6: & bottomD"). In VBA that would look like Range(Cells(6, 5), Cells(bottomD, 7)). That's easier to manipulate.

Comment: That doesn't really add any useful info to your question. If these rows are genuinely and completely blank delete them before copying. You can probably use `SpecialCells` to do that in one fell swoop.

Comment: Hi SJR, I just tried to populate dummy data in the empty rows and copied the whole range. At the end of pasting the range, I simply ran a code snippet to delete the dummy data rows. Bottom line, thanks for your advise, you made me think in the right direction.